# Al pulsar radio button desaparece el indicador checked

Tags: html, vue.js

Tengo un formulario dinamico que se crea con `vue`, todo bien hasta aqui, ahora bien, he agregado un evento `@change` con el metodo `setDependencyVisibility` y lo que pasa es muy extraño;

Si pulso 1 vez sobre cualquiera de los radio buttons la marca *(circulo que aparece dentro del radio button)* que indica que ese radio esta activo aparece 1ms y desaparece, para que se vea el marcador debo pulsarlo 2 veces.

Método `setDependencyVisibility`

```
setDependencyVisibility() {
    for (let field in this.fields_repository) {
        if (this.fields_repository[field].has_dependency == '1') {
            for (let index in this.fields_repository) {
                if (this.fields_repository[index].id == this.fields_repository[field].dependency.form_meta_data_id_on_who_depends) {
                    const radioGroup = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${this.fields_repository[index].name}"]`);
                    radioGroup.forEach(radio => {
                        if (radio.value == this.fields_repository[field].dependency.true_value) {
                            if (radio.checked === true) {
                                this.fields_repository[field].dependency.show = true;
                            } else {
                                this.fields_repository[field].dependency.show = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Contenido de `fields_repository`

```
fields_repository:Object
0:Object
    dependency:Object
        show:true
    has_dependency:"0"
    id:57
    length:25
    name:"tiene_trabajo"
    options:Array[2]
    required:false
    type:"radio"
1:Object
    dependency:Object
        form_meta_data_id:58
        form_meta_data_id_on_who_depends:57
        id_depending_field:3
        show:true
        true_value:"si"
    has_dependency:"1"
    id:58
    length:99999
    name:"salario"
    required:false
    type:"number"
2:Object
    dependency:Object
        form_meta_data_id:59
        form_meta_data_id_on_who_depends:57
        id_depending_field:4
        show:true
        true_value:"no"
    has_dependency:"1"
    id:59
    length:25
    name:"quien_lo_mantiene"
    required:false
    type:"text"
```

HTML

```html
<label>{{field.name.replace(/_/g, ' ')}}</label>
<span v-for="(option,option_index,key) in field.options">
    <input type="radio"
           :checked="option.default == 1"
           :value="option.option_value"
           :name="field.name"
           :id="field.name + option_index"
           @change="setDependencyVisibility()"
           required>

    <label :for="field.name + option_index">{{option.option_value}}</label>
</span>
```

conociendo el método que se activa cada vez que un radio cambia de estado, cabe resaltar que el problema radica en el ultimo `if` del metodo `setDependencyVisibility`

```
 if (radio.value == this.fields_repository[field].dependency.true_value) {
     if (radio.checked === true) {
         this.fields_repository[field].dependency.show = true;
     } else {
         this.fields_repository[field].dependency.show = false;
     }
 }
```

El comportamiento inusual desaparece cuando elimino ese fragmento.

Mi objetivo final es hacer campos dependientes de radio buttons, pero los formularios son dinámicos, en su totalidad, a tal punto que la aplicación tiene un constructor de formularios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resulto el problema, por alguna razon en el `HTML` el atributo `:checked="option.default == 1"` es el que provoca este comportamiento inusual.